# How to search a string and save the matched line in another file

Tags: python

I have a text file which looks like:

```
Type: Local Logon   Date:  7/28/2022 6:10:06 PM     Status: Success User:  USER     Workstation:  DESKTOP-I4FGAIL
Type: Local Logon   Date:  7/28/2022 6:10:06 PM     Status: Success User:  USER     Workstation:  DESKTOP-I4FGAIL
Type: Local Logon   Date:  7/28/2022 6:01:16 PM     Status: Success User:  USER     Workstation:  DESKTOP-I4FGAIL
Type: Local Logon   Date:  7/28/2022 6:01:16 PM     Status: Success User:  USER     Workstation:  DESKTOP-I4FGAIL
Type: Local Logon   Date:  7/28/2022 5:42:16 PM     Status: Success User:  USER     Workstation:  DESKTOP-I4FGAIL
Type: Local Logon   Date:  7/27/2022 4:13:27 PM     Status: Success User:  USER     Workstation:  DESKTOP-I4FGAIL
Type: Local Logon   Date:  7/27/2022 4:13:27 PM     Status: Success User:  USER     Workstation:  DESKTOP-I4FGAIL
Type: Local Logon   Date:  7/27/2022 11:11:27 AM    Status: Success User:  USER     Workstation:  DESKTOP-I4FGAIL
Type: Local Logon   Date:  7/27/2022 11:11:27 AM    Status: Success User:  USER     Workstation:  DESKTOP-I4FGAIL
Type: Local Logon   Date:  7/27/2022 11:10:53 AM    Status: Success User:  USER     Workstation:  DESKTOP-I4FGAIL
Type: Local Logon   Date:  7/27/2022 11:10:53 AM    Status: Success User:  USER     Workstation:  DESKTOP-I4FGAIL
```

I want to write a python code where I can find a specific string from the textfile, copy and save that exact line to another file. Lets say I want to search the date "7/28/2022" and save all the lines that contains the string.

```
import re
ans = input("What do you want to search?")
with open(r'D:\Cyber_security\Python\test.txt', "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        match = re.search(ans, line)
        print(match)
        myfile = open(r'D:\Cyber_security\Python\ab.txt', 'w+')
        myfile.write(match)
        myfile.close()
        if match is not None:
            print("Not found")
```

I tried this...but the result is "none" in match

Comment: What problems do you have? This is a really basic question, so I suppose you're learning programming - please include your attempt and explain what's wrong with it. Simple `for` loop with condition should work.

Comment: Please put it in your question ([edit]), not as comment: it is unreadable

Comment: I just tried your code, and when you input `7/28/2022`, it prints `<re.Match object; span=(27, 36), match='7/28/2022'>`. and then throws an error `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None`. That's expected since `match` gives back a [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects), not the matched text (which you can access with `match[0]`). But **this is not the behaviour you are describing**. Is it possible you are inputting `"7/28/2022"` (with double quotes)??

Comment: If you loop and open the file with `w+`, you are going to overwrite file in each loop. Consider using `a+` instead.

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to use regex when inputting the search string, or you just want the user to input the exact text? In the first case, your approach is correct, but in the second you would be making things unnecessary complicated.

Comment: I want the first case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you.

```
ans = input("What do you want to search?")
match = False
with open("scratch_8.txt", "r") as f, open("scratch_9.txt", "w+") as w:
    for line in f:
        if ans in line:
            match = True
            w.write(line)

if match:
    print("Found: " + ans)
else:
    print("Not found")
```

Comment: I tried your method...but it shows not found even if the string was in line in the txtfile @Ameen Ali Shaikh

Comment: Not sure how you are trying to execute or the input you provided to this script. Also you need to change the file names provided for it to work in your system. I tried it myself using the input provided in question and it works. I have nothing more to add here. Happy Coding

Comment: After trying in different drive it works...thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open("file_name", "r")
saved_lines = []
for line in file:
   if "Date: 7/28/2022" in line:
       saved_lines.append(line)
```

This will add all of the lines containing the desired date into a list

Comment: shouldn't be "for line in file.readlines()" ?

Comment: The question was about "save in another file",  so instead of appending you need just to write. And **close** the file, better - with context manager (`with open(...) as file: ...`)

Comment: @FaridFakhry nope. This solution is better (more memory efficient): file is an iterator and loops over lines, while `readlines()` puts all strings into memory and returns `list`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
subStr = "line to find"

readFile = [line for line in open("filetoread", "r") if subStr in line]
```

Comment: Not exact match, asker requires the line which has some text which is substring in the line. You case will work only for exact match.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the whole line that contains a regex, you don't need the regex to capture it. You can, of course, but you can also just check whether the regex is present and then just print the whole line that contains it.

Also, if you open in each iteration your file with mode "w+", python is going to create a new file in each loop, therefore overwriting the previous one, so you'll only keep the last result. You can use "a" to open the file in *append* mode (it will create the file if it doesn't exists).

```
import re
ans = r"7/28/2022"
with open(r'text.txt', "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.search(ans, line):
            with open(r'matches.txt', 'a+') as matches:
                matches.write(line)
        else:
            print("Not found")
```

Output:

```
Not found
Not found
Not found
Not found
Not found
Not found
```

And a matches.txt file with:

```
Type: Local Logon   Date:  7/28/2022 6:10:06 PM     Status: Success User:  USER     Workstation:  DESKTOP-I4FGAIL
Type: Local Logon   Date:  7/28/2022 6:10:06 PM     Status: Success User:  USER     Workstation:  DESKTOP-I4FGAIL
Type: Local Logon   Date:  7/28/2022 6:01:16 PM     Status: Success User:  USER     Workstation:  DESKTOP-I4FGAIL
Type: Local Logon   Date:  7/28/2022 6:01:16 PM     Status: Success User:  USER     Workstation:  DESKTOP-I4FGAIL
Type: Local Logon   Date:  7/28/2022 5:42:16 PM     Status: Success User:  USER     Workstation:  DESKTOP-I4FGAIL
```

Comment: I tried your solution but my matches.txt file is empty @Ignatius Reilly

Comment: I am using the input without quotes

Comment: I also tried ans = r"7/28/2022".... but same happens....the matches.txt is empty

Comment: yes...I also corrected the name of the files

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same as above, without 'input' and it works fine.

```
ans = "What do you want to search?"
match = False
with open("scratch_8.txt", "r") as f, open("scratch_9.txt", "w+") as w:
    for line in f:
        if ans in line:
            match = True
            w.write(line)

if match:
    print("Found: " + ans)
else:
    print("Not found")
```